# Unable to install .ipa on iphone due to integrity

Tags: azure-devops, ipa

I am able to create an .ipa for our xamarin.ios app using azure pipelines. I used the Xamarin.iOS task to generate the .ipa and uploaded it to AppCenter. However, when my teammates try to install the said file into an iphone, they are unable to and they get the error message, unable to install due to integrity cannot be verified.
If they manually create the package using xcode and upload it to AppCenter, they are able to install the app.
I am using the same p12 and provisioning profile that they are using.

Can some please tell me what should i do so that the package created using the pipeline can be installed?

below is the Xamarin task that I used. I also have tasks that install the certificate and the provisioning profile before this task.

- task: XamariniOS@2
  displayName: 'Build Xamarin.iOS solution'
  inputs:
  solutionFile: '*/ios.csproj'
  configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
  packageApp: true
  buildForSimulator: false
  runNugetRestore: false
  signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
  signingProvisioningProfileID: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'

Comment: Hey have you found resolution for this issue ? am facing this now